# Asymptotic Analysis of a Combinatorial Quantity

Tags: co.combinatorics

I am investigating a particular problem related with generalized derangements. It is as follows:

Imagine that you a have a collection of $2N$ objects each one of a unique type: $1,2,3$ or $4$. Objects of the same type are indistinguishable. You have $n_1$ objects of type $1$, ... and $n_4$ objects of type $4$. Here $n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4$ are given non-negative integers such that $n_1+n_2=n_3+n_4=N$.  You also have four boxes $Q_1,Q_2,Q_3$ and $Q_4$. Box $Q_1$ has room for $n_1$ objects, ... and box $Q_4$ has room for $n_4$ objects. Lets call by $A$ any general rearrangement of all the objects in the given boxes. For a given rearrangement $A$, denote by $A_1$ the number of objects of type $1$ in box $Q_1$, ... and by $A_4$ the number of objects of type $4$ in box $Q_4$.

The problem consists in finding a lower bound for the following quantity
$$
B(n_1,...,n_4)=\sum_{A} (-1)^{A_1+A_2+A_3+A_4}
$$
as $N\to\infty$. My conjecture is that 
$$
B(n_1,...,n_4)\geq \epsilon\frac{4^N}{N},
$$
where $\epsilon$ is a positive number independent of $n_1,n_2,n_3$ and $n_4$.

What is known is (see [Gillis and Kleeman](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/a-combinatorial-proof-of-a-positivity-result/6B394358B516FD6EC7F4531E4903999A)):

1)  $B$ is strictly positive .

2) There is huge closed formula for $B$ which is pretty hard to use for general asymptotic analysis. For a special case this mentioned formula implies that: $B(N/2,N/2,N/2,N/2)\sim C \frac{4^N \log(N)}{N}$ where $C=4/\pi^2$.

Any help would be awesome. This problem is annoying me for some weeks.

Best,

Felipe.

Comment: So, a general rearrangement is essentially a $4\times 4$ matrix $M$ with nonnegative entries and the sum of $i$-th row/column equal $n_i$. Then $B(n_1,\dots,n_4)=\sum_M (-1)^{\mathrm{tr}(M)}$. Correct?